# Flotr2 bar graph - data format error

Tags: arrays, json

I'm reading the ajax call and inserting values and tricks to array

```
        $.ajax({
            async: false, //thats the trick
            url: '/Test/Test.jsp',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){

                $.each(response, function(index, element) {
                    newdata.push(newdata.length, parseInt(element[1]));
                    newticks.push(newticks.length, element[0]);
                });

               data = response;

            }
            });
```

newdata array data in this format

```
0,20,1,60,2,10,3,67,4,76,5,10
```

but flotr expect data in `[[0, 20],[ 1, 60],[ 2, 10],[ 3, 67],[4,76]]`

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If response is a string: `"4,32,45,3,56,3,67..."`

You can write:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/idIJogoP/2/edit?js,console)

```
$.each(response.split(','), function (index, element){
    newdata.push(new Array(newdata.length, parseInt(element[1])));
    newticks.push(new Array(newticks.length, parseInt(element[0])));
});
```

or:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/idIJogoP/1/edit?js,console)

```
$.each(response.split(','), function (index, element){
    var temp = null;
    newdata.push(temp = [newdata.length, parseInt(element[1])]);
    newticks.push(temp = [newticks.length, parseInt(element[0])]);
});
```

I think the first variant is more clear to understand at first sight, but both are equivalent.

Comment: somehow your solution is not working.

JSON.stringify is working but giving result in string and flotr exoect in integer.

Any solution ??

Comment: i just added demos for simple static response arrays

Comment: response is the string? "12,13,14,15,..."?

Comment: Thanks Ruben..I think I should be more clear what I'm doing ..      $.ajax({
          async: false, //thats the trick
          url: '/Test/Test.jsp',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
           
           $.each(response, function(index, element) {
            newdata.push(new Array(newdata.length, parseInt(element[1])));
      newticks.push(newticks.length, element[0]);
              });
           
             data = response;
         
          }
       });  I'm expecting [[0, 20],[ 1, 60],[ 2, 10],[ 3, 67],[4,76]] from newdata. Is this possible?